# how can i use from methods in other pages?

Tags: php

HI,
i have 2 php pages.first page has some functions like Connect(),... .i want to use from Connect() function in second page but when use from Connect() can not recognize it.i use from header("first.php") but have same error.
how can i solve that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `include` the PHP file which contains your function(s).

In this case, if you're "index" page is called `index.php` and your function, `Connect()` is stored in `functions.php` then you would do:

**`index.php`**:

```
include "functions.php";
Connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class contains that method and include in the page where u want

Comment: i will give you +1 for your guidance.

Comment: Maybe because you should not create classes solely to be a container for functions.

Comment: And it should still be 'included' or 'required' which is the actual problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell us which error you get.

A solution would be to put all the functions you want to share in their own file, e.g. `functions.php` and then use [**`require`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) in both files to have access to those functions:

```
require 'functions.php';
```